# Report Viewer in Local Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reportviewer, rdlc

Is it possible to have the LOCAL mode RDLC reports to work in the load balanced environment?

For example, is it possible to have paginations in RDLC report? If so, how would the paginations work in load balanced environment with the Report Viewer in Local Mode?

Thanks!